# What are the URI/URL schemes for most IM networks?

Tags: url, uri, instant-messaging

I am looking for information abou URI schemes for most used IM/chat networks and phone.

Looking for URI for

- phone number `tel:` - already solved, [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)
- yahoo `ymsgr:addfriend?yourid`
- skype
- msn
- [XMPP/Jabber/Google talk](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0147.html)
- `sip:user@example.com`, also used by Microsoft Office Communicator

Note, I know that Skype supports `callme://` but I don't know if this is specific to Skype or where is the syntax described.

Comment: Don't assume the `//`. `tel:`, for example, doesn't use `//`.

Comment: Indeed, it's a schema-specific requirement. Solely the oldest of them use it still, since Berners-Lee doesn't like it (and it's a useless relic).

Answer (score 10):

To anyone who still finds this relevant, here's what I gathered:

| Service | Format |
| --- | --- |
| Email | `mailto:<email>?[Subject|CC|BCC|Body]` |
| Phone | `tel:<number>` |
| SMS | `sms:<number>` |
| IRC | `irc://<url>:[port|channel|password]` |
| FaceTime | `facetime:<number>` |
| Skype | `skype:<username|number>?[add|call|chat|sendfile|userinfo]` |
| Hangouts (formerly Google Talk) | <strike>`gtalk:[chat|call]?<email>`</strike> `com.google.hangouts:[chat|call]?<email>` |
| Windows Live Messenger (formerly MSN) | `msnim:[add|chat|voice|video]?<email>` |
| Yahoo! Messenger | `ymsgr:[sendim|addfriend|sendfile|call|callPhone|chat|im|customstatus|getimv]?<email|number>` |
| AIM | `aim:[goim|goaway|addbuddy]?<username>` |
| QQ | `mqq://<url>` |
| ICQ | `icq:message?uin=<number>` |
| Jabber, as already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464688/9731176 | `xmpp:username@domain.tld` |

Comment: Yes, it has. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know the URI for imo messenger?

Comment: "Email" should be "E-mail", @Fox.

Answer (score 1):

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0147.html (jabber is xmpp, google talk just uses xmpp)